# Cokernel of injective endomorphisms of a finitely generated free abelian group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

By $\text{GL}^+(n,\mathbb{Z})$ we mean the set of $n×n$ invertible matrices with positive determinant and entries from $\mathbb{Z}$. 
For given $A \in \text{GL}^+(n,\mathbb{Z})$ let 
$F_A=\mathbb{Z}^n/A\mathbb{Z}^n$ denote the cokernel of $A$.  I would like to compute $|F_A|$. How does one do this?

Comment: What do you mean by $\;A\Bbb Z^n\;$ ?

Comment: @Timbuc Most likely the image of $A$.

Comment: @Timbuc  $A\mathbb{Z}^n=\{Av\mid v\in \mathbb{Z}^n\}$, $v$ here considered as column vector

Comment: Q: *How does one do this?* A: Smith normal form.

Comment: @blue If B is the Smith normal form of A, do you mean that $F_A=F_B$

Comment: Yes. Well, $F_A\cong F_B$ technically.

Comment: @blue Not sure how to prove $F_A\cong F_B$. I guess that we need to prove that $F_A=F_{GA}=F_{AG}$ for every $G\in \text{GL}^+(n,\mathbb{Z})$ with $\det(G)=1$? :)

Comment: We have $\Bbb Z^n/AG\Bbb Z^n=\Bbb Z^n/A\Bbb Z^n$ for every matrix $G$ such that $G\Bbb Z^n=\Bbb Z^n$ (namely, the invertible matrices), and we have $G:\Bbb Z^n/A\Bbb Z^n\cong\Bbb Z^n/GA\Bbb Z^n$ via $v+A\Bbb Z^n\mapsto Gv+GA\Bbb Z^n$.